# How does Unity resolve types that have not been registered?

Tags: c#, .net, ioc-container

I'll admit it, I'm too lazy to look at the source code. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660864(PandP.20).aspx):

> You can use the Unity container to generate instances of any object that has a public constructor (in other words, objects that you can create using the new operator), without registering a mapping for that type with the container. When you call the Resolve method and specify the default instance of a type that is not registered, the container simply calls the constructor for that type and returns the result.